# Elasticsearch: get total of GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the elasticsearch java client and I want to work out how many distinct items items there are matching a combination. I'm currently using facets like this:

```
client.prepareSearch(indexName)
      .addFacet(Efb.termsFacet("hotels")
        .field("hotel.specialCode")
        .script("term + ';;;' + _source.hotel.name + ';;;' + _source.offer.destinationId")
        .facetFilter(filter)
        .size(50))
```

I then get the total using:

```
case tf: TermsFacet =>
        val entries = tf.getEntries
        val totalHotels = entries.size()
```

This is wrong because I am asking for the total returned, which in my query I limited to 50 - so this number will never exceed 50.

How can I get the total number of facets, without having to pull them all back into memory? Or is there a better way to do the equivalent of a SQL GROUP BY and COUNT in elasticsearch?

Comment: If you're interested in the total for each group (=facet), I don't see how you could avoid pulling them all into memory. If you only want to know how many distinct combinations there are, you might want to look at aggregations rather than facets.

Comment: ok didn't know about aggregation before. will take a look and report back

Comment: You can post the JSON request to elastic search API and the JSON request will have the query to get the count using group by. Take the reference of answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751060/how-to-include-group-clause-in-count-api-of-elasticsearch/56752801#56752801