# How to include group clause in count API of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For my application I'm using count API provided by elasticsearch for getting the aggregate value for my search queries in Java using RestHighLevel Client. However I'm facing a situation where I need to get the aggregate based on the currency for which I need to include group by condition. Any idea on how to add group by condition using count API Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the sample query to get the count using the aggregate function.

```
 {
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "columnid" : {
        "value" : 1,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  },
  "_source" : false,
  "stored_fields" : "_none_",
  "aggregations" : {
    "groupby" : {
      "composite" : {
        "size" : 10,
        "sources" : [
          {
            "14" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "columnid",
                "missing_bucket" : true,
                "order" : "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Also use can translate your SQL query into kibana query using following query-

```
 POST _xpack/sql/translate
    {
       "query": "SELECT COUNT(*), columnid FROM Indexname WHERE columnid=1 group by columnid ",
       "fetch_size": 10
    }
```

Please mark answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: First, use kibana to generate query after that post this query to the elastic search API. Also, you can verify the query using POSTMAN (chrome plugin)

Comment: This the json you need to post to the elastic search API. Take the reference from the   below link for json post
https://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/